# CENTOS 7 nginx issue

Tags: nginx, centos7

I am not a developer, but just know how to work with google, which means i lack a lot of knowledge. I work for an NGO here, and we have received free hosting to build the site on. I can build sites (wordpress) but have always worked through hosting like godaddy. Now we have cloud through a company called BMIT, and i am struggling to install
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7

So far everything worked, created a different root etc, but when installing nginx this works, but when running

sudo systemctl start nginx I get an error and this is
[image: error]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

inspect the log file located on `/var/log/nginx/`, there you can find error log file and reason

Comment: add the log file content in question